# Where is the user's picture stored in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using a SelectQuery object to retrieve and display a list of users, but I don't know where to get the user's picture from.

The users table has a column called picture, but the data in there is just an integer. Is the picture stored in a blob field somewhere or is there a link to the picture in another table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image file itself is stored (usually) somewhere in `/sites/default/files`. The reference to that image is stored in the `file_managed` table, the `picture` column in the `users` table contains the `fid` (file id) of the picture.

You can load the file object like this:

```
$file = file_load($fid);
```

And get the output for the image like this:

```
$image = theme('image', array('path' => $file->uri, 'alt' => 'Alt text'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello please user this code :

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
$uid = 99;
$account = user_load($uid);
// get image information
$image_path = 'public://avatars/upload/b8f1e69e83aa12cdd3d2babfbcd1fe27_4.gif';
$image_info = image_get_info($image_path);
?>
```

For get user avatar uri;

Thanks,
JAY