# Where does drupal saves images path i've uploaded from a content type in its table?

Tags: php, drupal

I have created a content type gallery. I have the fields description and image, I want to retrieve all data from content type gallery .I do not know where drupal saves image paths from a content type. It would be great if someone could help me with this. I just want the table name where drupal saves image uploaded in customized contents..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the user's picture stored in Drupal 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432955/where-is-the-users-picture-stored-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 7):

I believe the table you are looking for is *file_managed* (Drupal 7) or *files* (Drupal 6). This will give you paths to the uploaded images.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal don't cares what content type is used, images are in file_managed table also you can find image url in your node array. Try `<?php drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($node, true).'</pre>');?>` in your node.tpl.php file.